# How to remove the "button" effect for a menu item (WPF)

Tags: wpf

When the mouse is over a menu item (first level) it displays a 3D button effect. How can this be removed?

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**:

Tried

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0">
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

with no effect.

The menu XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="UCWPF.Window3"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:UCWPF.Converters"
    Title="Window3" Height="600" Width="600"
    Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
    >

<StackPanel Style="{StaticResource WindowContainerStyle}">
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="New" Icon="{StaticResource ImageNew}" />
        <MenuItem Header="Open" Icon="{StaticResource ImageOpen}" />
        <MenuItem Header="Save" Icon="{StaticResource ImageSave}" />
        <MenuItem Header="Export" Icon="{StaticResource ImageExport}" />
    </Menu>
...
```

And here's the screenshot:
[bordereffect http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/6517/menuborder.png](http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/6517/menuborder.png)

---

**EDIT 2**:

With great power comes great ... complexity :(.

It looks like the whole menu template should be redefined to achieve my purpose. The 3D effect is given by a MenuItem child border (identified with Snoop) which, on mouse over, sets its BorderStyle to raised. I don't know if that border style can be touched inside the `<Style TargetType="MenuItem">`  element, any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post your menu XAML and maybe a screenshot.

Comment: Now post WindowContainerStyle. What you need to do is define a new style for menu and/or menuitem which has the look you prefer instead of whatever is in WindowContainerStyle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type MenuItem}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
<Style.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true"/>
  </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

```
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
<Border Name="Border" >
  <Grid>
    <ContentPresenter
      Margin="6,3,6,3"
      ContentSource="Header"
      RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
    <Popup
      Name="Popup"
      Placement="Bottom"
      IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}"
      AllowsTransparency="True"
      Focusable="False"
      PopupAnimation="Fade">
      <Border
        Name="SubmenuBorder"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
        Background="{DynamicResource NormalBrush}"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"
        BorderThickness="1" >
        <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True"
          Style="{StaticResource MenuScrollViewer}">
          <StackPanel
          IsItemsHost="True"
          KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
        </ScrollViewer>
      </Border>
    </Popup>
  </Grid>
</Border>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
    <Setter TargetName="Popup" Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None"/>
  </Trigger>
  <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"/>
    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
  </Trigger>
  <!--Snippettoplevelheader-->
  <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,4,4"/>
    <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,3"/>
  </Trigger>
  <!--/Snippettoplevelheader-->
  <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
  </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

The trigger IsHighlighted defines the style when the mouse is over, if you remove the trigger, nothing is displayed when the mouse is moved over the top menu

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771597%28VS.85%29.aspx for more control styling examples

Answer (score 3):

```
<MenuItem Header="Menu...">
            <MenuItem Header="(none)"/>
            <Separator/>

            <MenuItem>
                <MenuItem.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding .}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </MenuItem.Template>
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
```

Comment: That's actually a quite good and simple solution for modifying the menu.